# Map two tables based on range day in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm looking to find out how i can write an oracle query to cross information between two tables and put those dynamically together

For example i have the following data from TABLE 1 where the 'PRODUCT' need to be matched from TABLE 2 (WHERE T1.DN = T2.NO)

[image: TABLE 1]

the PRODUCT description is on Table2: PROD_TYPE

[image: TABLE 2]

the result should as below

[image: FINAL]

Essentially  I would like to map dynamically for each date and product on table 1 select the right product_type in that period from t2, but i'm not sure how i would do that

I tried the below code but the result is not as expected, please need some advice, would appreciate it if somebody could help.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE1 A
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B
    ON TABLE1.DN = TABLE2.NO and (DATE BETWEEN INTRO_DATE AND REMOVAL_DATE )
    where TABLE1.DN = 6755
```

Answer (score 0):

You select *, which means you will get all the columns from both tables. Is that the only way in which this "didn't work"? The query looks right (except if you are going to use the full table names everywhere, it is not clear why you are aliasing them; usually one would write where a.dn = b.no, etc.)

The problem is with your data. If you use "between" that includes both ends. In your TABLE2 one interval ends on June 10 and the next begins also on June 10. If that's how it must remain (REMOVAL means no longer "current" on the removal date), then you can fix that in the query by changing "REMOVAL_DATE" to REMOVAL_DATE - 1   in the "BETWEEN" clause.